# Kibana : Is there a way to get dashboards from command line?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, elasticsearch-2.0

In Kibana Settings/Objects menu, i can see all of my dashboards, charts and searches.

I can choose to export one or more of them and then i get a JSON object representing that item.

Is there a way to do this from command line? Where are the dashboards stored in elasticsearch? Is there a way to access them using the .kibana index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get complete Kibana metadata from command line using cURL. Only thing you need to have is access to Elasticsearch.

Elasticsearch stores complete Kibana metadata in `.kibana` (default and if you want it to store in new index then you can configure it in kibana.yml). Using Elasticsearch `GET API` you can retrieve `index-patterns`, `visualizations`, `dashboards`, `kibana settings` etc.

Examples to get Kibana visualizations and dashboards:

```
curl -XGET "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200/.kibana/dashboard/dashboard_name?pretty=1"
curl -XGET "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200/.kibana/visualization/visualization_name?pretty=1"
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: How to retrieve all the dashboards from the elastic search instead of searching by each dashboard name?

Answer (score 1):

All the settings, including the dashboard settings, are stored in the .kibana index (by default) of your connected Elasticsearch cluster.

On GitHub there are several scripts that can be used to export and import an index of elasticsearch. We use https://github.com/mallocator/Elasticsearch-Exporter to sync Kibana settings between OTAP. We can export settings from an environment to SVN (jenkins job) and import from SVN to another environment.